# No empty dir in tar log

Tags: linux, output, tar, logfile

Hi I'm writing a shell for backup the file in my system that are changed after yesterday.
The tar logfile is scanned and every row goes in an oracle database table.

The problem is that when the tar find a directory without file, it puts the directory in the logfile.

My command is:

```
for DIR in $( cat .backup_sys_tape_include.txt )
do
 tar -cvzf ${HOSTNAME}_${DATE}_DAY$(echo ${DIR} | sed -e 's/\//_/g').tgz  ${DIR} --exclude-from=.backup_sys_tape_exclude.txt --after-date="${YESTERDAY}" > OK_${HOSTNAME}$(echo ${DIR} | sed -e 's/\//_/g').out 2> KO_${HOSTNAME}$(echo ${DIR} | sed -e 's/\//_/g').out
done
```

Where

```
INCLUDE_FILE -> file with system dir (every dir have a different tar)
FILE_TAR -> path/of/the/tar.tgz
EXCLUDE_FILE -> file with system dir to exclude from backup
YESTERDAY -> Yesterday date
OUTFILE_OK -> Log 
OUTFILE_KO -> Error log
```

For example the dir /etc/cron.weekly/ doesn't have file changed but this dir goes  in the tar log.

Comment: please complete your question with put value of all your variables.

Comment: Don't show us the documentation, show us the real code (with simplified data if need-be) , i.e. `INCLUDE_FILE="/path/to/include/myFile.h`, etc. Not that if you have spaces in your assigned values, you need to surround them in dbl-quotes as in this example. Good luck.